# Why does the ideal gas law exactly match the van't Hoff law for osmotic pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, kinetic-theory, gas, osmosis

The van't Hoff law for osmotic pressure $\Pi$ is
$$\Pi V=nRT$$
which looks similar to the ideal gas law
$$PV = nRT.$$
Why is this? Also, in biology textbooks, the van't Hoff law is usually instead written as 
$$\Pi=CRT =\frac{NC_m RT}M$$
where $C_m$ is the mass concentration, $N$ the number of ions, and $R$ the ideal gas constant. Why?

Comment: What law is that?

Comment: @BobD Van't Hoff law, the other one is the Ideal gas law !

Comment: What's the signification of $C_m$ and $N$ ?

Comment: I know about the ideal gas law. Just never hear of Van't Hoff law.

Comment: @Electroelf I added the signification

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The law $PV = n RT$ gives the pressure $P$ of $n$ moles of ideal gas in volume $V$. Meanwhile, the law $\Pi V = n R T$ describes the osmotic pressure $\Pi$ due to $n$ moles of solute in volume $V$.

These are qualitatively very different situations, but there's a simple fundamental reason that they end up looking the same. Both of these laws are derived under the idealized assumption that the ideal gas/solute molecules don't interact with each other at all. So the expressions for the entropy of the ideal gas/solute are the same, and since the pressure of a system can be [derived from the entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_force#Pressure_of_an_ideal_gas), both situations yield the same pressure.

The reason that you see $\Pi V = n RT$ expressed in such different units in biology textbooks is simply because they're using the units that are most convenient for them.

Answer (score 4):

I'm answering your 2nd question:

It's a really easy proof :

You have $C_m=\frac{m}V$ and $C=\frac{n}V$ where $n=\frac{m}M$, thus $C=\frac{C_m}M$

Therefore :
$$\Pi=\frac{C_m R T}{M}$$
For $N$ the ions number it's related to biology, the ions are interacting and they cause this pressure, For example if it's $\mathrm{NaCl}$ the ions are $N=2$

Thus Van't hoff law is written in Biology and Biophysics textbooks :
$$\Pi =\frac{NC_mRT}M$$